# Adding stylesheet to Bokeh App

Tags: python, bokeh

I have made a big complicated Bokeh dashboard.  I have not defined any html templates for the dashboard.  I have simply served it using the code below.

My problem is, the dashboard looked very nice when using the `bokeh.plotting.output_notebook` function to embed it into a Jupyter notebook.  Now, when trying to create and serve the dashboard outside of Jupyter, it looks much uglier because some stylesheets that render pretty tables aren't there.  My question is, **how do I get external stylesheets into my bokeh webapp.**

Dashboard Code:

```
def emb_bokehdash(self, doc, dash_width=1500, dash_height=800):
    # Get base data:
    df_orig = self._get_base_data_for_vis(unlabeled_name)
    unique_labels = list(df_orig.label.unique())

    ...

    # Sentence Selection Controls:
    index_text = AutocompleteInput(
        title="select sentence index", value=str(candidate_state),
        completions=list(df_orig.index.map(lambda idx: str(idx))),
        width=control_width
    )
    index_next = Button(label="next", button_type="primary", width=button_width)
    index_back = Button(label="back", button_type="primary", width=button_width)
    selection_checkboxes = CheckboxGroup(labels=['unseen', 'random'], active=[])

    index_input = row(
        widgetbox(index_text, width=control_width+200),
        widgetbox(index_next, index_back, width=button_width+40),
        selection_checkboxes,
        width=info_width
    )

    ... More code defining DOM and wrangling data

    layout_ = row(inputs_and_info, plot, height=dash_height)

    # initial load of the data
    update_selectioninfo_and_plot()
    update_selected_info()

    # Register title and dashboard with the document:
    doc.title = "Smart Feedback Labeler"
    doc.add_root(layout_)
```

Dashboard Server Code:

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from os import getpid

def emb_bokehdash_serve(self, **server_kwargs):
    # Route App:
    apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(self.bokeh_dashboard))}

    # Extract Port (default = 5000):
    if "port" not in server_kwargs:
        server_kwargs["port"] = 5000

    # Find a suitable port to use:
    while True:
        try:
            server = Server(apps, **server_kwargs)
        except OSError:
            self.logger.info(
                f"Port {server_kwargs['port']} already in use, serving to port {server_kwargs['port']+1}"
            )
            server_kwargs["port"] += 1
        else:
            break

    # We have to defer opening in browser until we start up the server
    def show_callback():
        for route in apps.keys():
            server.show(route)
    server.io_loop.add_callback(show_callback)

    # Set server address (default is localhost):
    address_string = 'localhost'
    if server.address is not None and server.address != '':
        address_string = server.address

    for route in sorted(apps.keys()):
        url = "http://%s:%d%s%s" % (address_string, server.port, server.prefix, route)
        self.logger.info("Bokeh app running at: %s" % url)

    self.logger.info("Starting Bokeh server with process id: %d" % getpid())

    if not run_from_ipython():
        server.run_until_shutdown()  # Doesn't shutdown properly when run from Jupyter Notebook.
    else:
        server.start()
```

Note, I cannot run this dashboard statically.

Comment: Did the answer below help resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't experience your problem as I skipped the Jupyter part and built a standalone dashboard from the get-go. However, I used stylesheets to customize the dashboard look and its elements in the following way:

- Inside the dashboard directory, I have `templates/index.html` with:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
>   <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <title>{{ TITLE }}</title>
>     {{ bokeh_css }}
>     {{ bokeh_js }}
>     <style>
>       {% include 'styles.css' %}
>     </style>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div>
>     {{ plot_div|indent(8) }}
>     {{ plot_script|indent(8) }}
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

- Inside `templates/styles.css`, I have my css customizations.
- To apply a specific customization to a widget, the dashboard code needs to include: `<widget object>.css_classes = ["<class from templates/styles.css>"]`. It could be a list of strings in such assignment.

Does this make sense? I hope this helps.